# How can I run a jar with selenium in other computer?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a bunch of questions related to selenium, my objetive is run the program in other computer without change the code or the path are in it, and also without download anything except the jar.

I did a program using selenium and I need the firefox driver or chrome driver (both are .exe) to run the browser, its posible to run it in other computers including all in a packege, I mean without download it in the other computers and change the path?  I don't know how to do it.

I did it in java, can I put it in a server and run it from there (despite I need to it in other language)?

I don't mind to do it in another language if it's possible to do it.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible.

Comment: I'm confused what exactly youre asking.  You want to be able to run your tests without the need of downloading selenium on other computers using java?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Also if I could put it on a web (server) to run it wherever

Comment: @limit2001 what IDE are you using?

Comment: @NicolePhillips I'm using NetBeans 8.1

Comment: @limit2001 give this blog a look and let me know if this is what you are looking for http://arunasujith.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for a way to package your libraries into your jar file using netbeans.  This is not as easy as using eclipse but please review the below blog site to setup a FAT .jar file to be ran on other computers.

http://arunasujith.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html

If you need help getting the .jar files for selenium please review this site and do this before creating your FAT .jar.

http://startingwithseleniumwebdriver.blogspot.com/2013/11/here-we-try-to-configure-selenium-web.html

Comment: Thanks! I will need it too, but the problem that I have is I need to put a path to run the browser: System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path of geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: So could I put an exe in a fat jar?